# How to use aryule() in Matlab to extend a number series?

Tags: matlab, time-series, linear-regression

I have a series of numbers. I calculated the **"auto-regression"** between them using  **[Yule-Walker method](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/signal/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/signal/aryule.html)**.

**But now how do I extend the series?**

Whole working is as follows:

a) the series I use:

> `143.85 141.95 141.45 142.30 140.60 140.00 138.40 137.10 138.90 139.85 138.75 139.85 141.30 139.45 140.15 140.80 142.50 143.00 142.35 143.00 142.55 140.50 141.25 140.55 141.45 142.05`

b) this data is loaded in to **data** using:

```
data = load('c:\\input.txt', '-ascii');
```

c) the calculation of the coefficients:

```
ar_coeffs = aryule(data,9);
```

this gives:

```
ar_coeffs =
 1.0000 -0.9687 -0.0033 -0.0103 0.0137 -0.0129 0.0086 0.0029 -0.0149 0.0310
```

d) **Now using this, how do I calculate the next number in the series?**

[any other method of doing this (except using aryule()) is also fine... this is what I did, if you have a better idea, please let me know!]

Comment: So data is essentially the vector you posted in (a) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a real valued sequence x of length N, and a positive order p:

```
coeff = aryule(x, p)
```

returns the AR coefficients of order p of the data x (Note that coeff(1) is a normalizing factor). In other words it models values as a linear combination of the past p values. So to predict the next value, we use the last p values as:

```
x(N+1) = sum_[k=0:p] ( coeff(k)*x(N-k) )
```

or in actual MATLAB code:

```
p = 9;
data = [...];      % the seq you gave
coeffs = aryule(data, p);
nextValue = -coeffs(2:end) * data(end:-1:end-p+1)';
```

**EDIT:** If you have access to *System Identification Toolbox*, then you can use any of a number of functions to estimate AR/ARMAX models (**ar**/**arx**/**armax**) (or even find the order of AR model using **selstruc**):

```
m = ar(data, p, 'yw');    % yw for Yule-Walker method
pred = predict(m, data, 1);

coeffs = m.a;
nextValue = pred(end);

subplot(121), plot(data)
subplot(122), plot( cell2mat(pred) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data has a non-zero mean.  Doesn't the Yule-Walker model assume the data is the output of a linear filter excited by a zero-mean white noise process?

If you remove the mean, [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/signal/lpcardemo.html) using ARYULE and LPC might be what you're looking for.  The procedure boils down to:

```
a = lpc(data,9); % uses Yule-Walker modeling
pred = filter(-a(2:end),1,data);
disp(pred(end)); % the predicted value at time N+1
```